# Organize posts under custom category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've been working on this for two straight days and I can't for the life of me figure this thing out.

I have a custom post type **'teams'** that has custom categories assigned to it called 'boys division' and I'm trying to add code to my template that would display all the posts assigned to this custom category.

For example, I'd like to have it displayed like this:

### Boys U10

Panthers

Cobras

Aztecs

### Boys U12

Stars

Kings

Ducks

Cosmos

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried Googling this 100 times and nothing seems to work. Here's what I have...

```
<?php
    //for each category, show posts
    $cat_args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
       );
    $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
      foreach($categories as $category) {
        $args=array(
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'showposts' => -1,
          'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
          'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
        $posts=get_posts($args);
          if ($posts) {
            echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
            foreach($posts as $post) {
              setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
              <?php
            } 
          } 
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: I haven't double checked all the parameters but your code looks like a good start. Does it generate anything useful at all? Are there any errors?

Comment: It's displaying the posts and categories from the standard categories but not my custom categories and custom posts

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the code you have provided works but selects categories from the wrong taxonomy. In that case, all you need to do is change the taxonomy from which you select categories, which [can be done](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) by adding the parameter "taxonomy" in `$cat_args`.

```
$cat_args=array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'taxonomy' => 'teams_taxonomy'
);
```

I don't know what your taxonomy is called. But you have registered it somewhere so you can look it up, the function you used to register the taxonomy for teams is `register_taxonomy`.

Comment: I've tried that before but, unfortunately, it doesn't return any results. I've double and triple checked to make sure all my names are correct and they are so I'm not sure where else to turn.

Comment: I just did a var_dump and I can see that the variable is holding the correct information, I'm just having a difficult time now getting it to display

Comment: What did you use var_dump on? $categories? $posts? You could try using the post object directly instead of using the template tags. Just skip  setup_postdata and use $post->post_title instead (you can see the properties in your var dump)